# Nodejs/express server uses one socket.id for 2 RN clients in message saving

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The nodejs (10.16) and express (4.16) backend server (server) runs with socket.io 2.2.0 for a chat app. The message received on the server will be broadcast to the clients connecting to the same room (channel). The socket.io instance is created in index.js:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {

    socket.my_id = "";
    console.log("socket.id : ", socket.id);
    app.set("socket", socket);
    console.log("Socketio server is initialized");

    //disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', async function() {
        //if (socket.my_id) helper.RemoveSocketUser(user.fort_token, socket.my_id);
        console.log('disconnected event');
    });

});

server.listen(port, () => {};
```

Then after a message is saved on the server, the socket is used to broadcast to the clients in the same room.

```
try {
        await msg.save();
        msg.user_name = req.user.name;
        msg.user_avatar = req.user.user_data.avatar;
        const io = req.app.get("io");
        const socket = req.app.get('socket');
        const room = msg.event_id.toString();
        socket.my_id = req.user.id;
        socket.join(room);
        console.log("socket in new message : ", socket.id);
        console.log("msg before broadcast : ", msg.data.msg_body);
        io.to(room).emit("event message", msg);
        return res.status(200).send(req.body.data.msg_body);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error in saving/braodcasting a new message", err);
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    };
```

From the console output, the socket.id is the same for 2 clients connecting to the same room and chatting. Here is a output for Android emulator running on port 8081:

```
socket in new message :  b0po9l6hGZUi9xVDAAAE
msg before broadcast :  8081
```

Here is another android emulator running on port 9090:

```
socket in new message :  b0po9l6hGZUi9xVDAAAE
msg before broadcast :  9090
```

However the socket.id on clients side is not the same. What causes the server using the same socket.id for 2 clients?

Comment: You get the socket by calling `req.app.get('socket')` so the question is Is it the same socket or is it unique for each user?

Comment: Ok, i just noticed this `app.set("socket", socket);` which means the socket is always the last connected one. So yes it all make sense since you use same socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is accessing socket object stored in express,
which will update socket object every time new socket get connected that's why you are getting same socket id [ last connected ].

to access specific socket from outside the io connection scope, you have to get the socket instance from `io` object.

you need to store socket id somewhere in database or memory like redis.

```
const socketid = `get user's latest connected socket id.`
cont socket = io.sockets.sockets[socketid];
socket.emit('req', { data: "something"})
```

Comment: `cont socket = io.sockets.connected[socketid]` works.